# Busybox: Find all files on partition that have been modified since power-on

Tags: find, partition, busybox

I am trying to come up with a Busybox-compatible script (or one-liner) that lists every file *inside a specified partition* that has been modified since the last power-on. This should include files that were written during boot, where possible. It should not include files that are mounted separately to the specified partition e.g if I ask it to search the root partition `/` then it should automatically exclude `/dev` because it is a separate `devtmpfs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find / -xdev -type f -newer /proc/1` ought to deliver same results, and a little simpler/shorter.

Answer (score 2):

This command did the trick:

```
find / -xdev -type f -mmin -`cat /proc/uptime | cut -f1 -d" " | awk '{printf("%d", $1 / 60)}'`
```